# Open source political campaign management software?

Tags: open-source

Does anyone know of any active open source projects working on political campaign management software?

I looked on sourceforge but didn't see anything relevant from the queries "political", "politics", "donations", "campaign", or in the categories "accounting", "politics" or "voting".

I'm involved with a political campaign that is currently paying out the nose for some horribly designed SaaS (whose Name i Guess i should Protect, ahem) to basically just keep track of donations people have made now, donations people have made in the past, donations people have pledged to make, contact information, the way they will likely vote, etc.

It's a bit much to manage in spreadsheets, but doesn't seem like it's something complex enough that political campaigns should have to pay for (especially low-budget local ones).

I'd love to help out if such a project exists, or start/revive one if it doesn't.

Any hints, places to look, etc are much appreciated.

Comment: That's a lot of tracking for a single political campaign.  From what I've seen, vote tracking is usually done through the political party.

Comment: +1 Never occurred to me to even think such a thing would exist. Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, we have data from the party but want to merge it with our own canvassing, etc since we have limited resources, so for instance we can target people who are most likely to vote in a municipal primary, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drupal CMS has modules which can probably help. Although I don't have any experience in using these modules you can look at [CiviCRM](http://civicrm.org/).

A search at [drupalmodules.com](http://drupalmodules.com/search/node/campaign+management) also revealed some other modules.

Comment: Thank you!! CiviCRM sounds really close to what I'm looking for :D

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any exactly. However, you could probably use some off the shelf open source solution that is not targeted specifically as campaigns. Perhaps you could use many kinds of project management or even *bug tracking* type of applications to help. As far as tracking donations, you should be able to find some open source project to fill this need, even if it is not that specific. You could even write this without too much trouble if needed.

Edit, here is one CRM project that purports to work with campaign management:

http://sourcetapcrm.sourceforge.net/

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you for your suggestions :D

Answer (score 1):

CiviCRM is a Drupal, Joomla or standalone software package to help nonprofits.

It can:

1. run mailing lists
2. subscribe members
3. process donations
4. manage event registration and payment

It shoudl be suitable for a political campaign

I work with CiviCRM a lot

Answer (score 1):

I'm the creator of Voter Universe, a new open source web application for helping political campaigns and political organizations analyze and interact with their voter data.  The application is still in active development, but we expect to have our first production release in October 2009 as well as the launch of an affordably priced hosted service.

The first release will not include donor management, but that functionality is a high priority item after the first release.

I created a screencast a few weeks ago in advance of starting to spread the word about the application at Netroots Nation.  You can view the screencast at our website, http://www.voteruniverse.com

Jason Lantz

Comment: Fantastic! I'm actually in Pittsburgh but couldn't make it to Netroots Nation. The candidates I volunteer for would definitely agree to your platform, and I admire your views on open source and politics. I just joined your mailing list, I'd love to help out if I can!

Comment: Hi carolclarinet.  Thanks for the feedback and support.  Netroots Nation was truly an awesome experience, sad you couldn't make it.  We should have an online demo available sometime in October followed shortly by the first production release.  We'll be sending advanced access to our mailing list, so keep an eye out.

Comment: @Jason http://www.voteruniverse.com seems to be down

Answer (score 1):

'To basically just keep track of donations people have made now, donations people have made in the past, donations people have pledged to make, contact information, the way they will likely vote, etc.': in the absense of a proper tailor made program I would manipulate QuickBooks - by creating an invoice for pledges on the date they're made while issuing receipts on the dates donations are collected; as well as creating a bank account to deposit all monies and writing checks to track all expences. The contact info part is easy. To track the way people will likely vote I will create party-items which will be used on the sales or service line when creating the invoice e.g. partyA-item, partyB-item, partyC-item etc and will pull up the specific sales/service graph to moniter vote pattern. I trust that you find my advice useful.